# How can an activity use a Toolbar without extending AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I have an activity `HomeView` which already extends another activity and it cannot extend `AppCompatActivity`. But HomeView needs to have a Toolbar. The Android documentation says that any activity which needs to have a Toolbar must extend `AppCompatActivity`.

How can I get around this limitation?

Comment: Just add the toolbar to your layout and you should be fine. I use toolbars  basically everywhere.

Comment: Don't I need to call `setSupportActionBar()`?

Comment: Why can't you use `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: I have implemented a `Model-View_Presenter` design in which every activity inherits from a GenericActivity. So the activity cannot inherit from AppCompatActivity.

Comment: But your GenericActivity could subclass AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @mvai Yes. I could do that and it would probably work. But, going forward I may need to inherit from something else and then I would be back to the same situation.

Comment: That is *very* uncommon, however for this particular case Google developed appcompatdelegate. The answer below is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `AppCompatCallback` and use `AppCompatDelegate`. Here's an excellent article about how to use it: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3#.nuyghrgr9 and also check out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html for knowing which methods to delegate.

---

#### [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html)

This class represents a delegate which you can use to extend AppCompat's support to any Activity.

When using an AppCompatDelegate, you should any methods exposed in it rather than the Activity method of the same name. This applies to:

```
addContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
setContentView(int)
setContentView(android.view.View)
setContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
requestWindowFeature(int)
invalidateOptionsMenu()
startSupportActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback)
setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)
getSupportActionBar()
getMenuInflater()
```

There also some Activity lifecycle methods which should be proxied to the delegate:

```
onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)
onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)
setTitle(CharSequence)
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

Comment: I asked another question related to this here [Why should I use AppCompatActivity insted of a standalone Toolbar to create an Activity's app bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428651/why-should-i-use-appcompatactivity-insted-of-a-standalone-toolbar-to-create-an-a)

Comment: @Amit that's a different question. You should perhaps accept the answer as correct so that others may benefit in future as well. Besides, I answered your question there too, check that out.

Comment: The first link to the tutorial is very helpful to break down & understand the steps. Additional considerations for me include: 1) making sure the toolbar layout is above the main content layout [it was getting hidden in my RelativeLayout] , 2) up navigation back button needs to be supported, and 3) Seems the text color needs to be set as well.  This is great to get going toward a solution tho .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is pretty simple:

```
public class YourActivity extends SomeActivity implements AppCompatCallback {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // create the delegate
    delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
    delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    // add the Toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    delegate.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    // leave it empty
  }

  @Override
  public void onSupportActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
    // leave it empty
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public ActionMode onWindowStartingSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
    return null;
  }
```

That's it. Please, don't forget to set a `AppTheme.NoActionBar` theme to `YourActivity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.