# Why should I use AppCompatActivity instead of a standalone Toolbar to create an Activity's app bar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

There are two principal ways of creating an app bar for an activity in API 21+ using the Toolbar.

1. Create an activity which extends AppCompatActivity and then follow the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)
2. Create a standalone `Toolbar`which acts as an app bar (define the Toolbar in xml using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`) and then inflate a menu into it like this: `     toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.homeview_menu_common);

My question is: what are the benefits and drawbacks of doing one over the other?`

A related question to this topic can also be found here ([How can an activity use a Toolbar without extending AppCompatActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358046/how-can-an-activity-use-a-toolbar-without-extending-appcompatactivity))

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: No you should make your activity extend AppCompatActivty

You can create a toolbar without AppCompatActivty but besides an app bar the AppCompat also brings with it the support libraries that allow you to add material design to your app going as far back as API level 7 of Android.

Unless there is a specific reason for not using AppCompat all your Activites should extend AppCompatActivty to model a Material app.

Comment: `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` also gives Toolbar compatibility for previous android versions

Comment: AppCompat is a collection of [support libraries] and default [styles] for android L/M(depending on version). Think of it this way, if you only pull in Toolbar then you also have to pull in button style, nav bar style, dialog style... Surely you can customize a button style yourself but you are not guaranteed that the button will look the same across all devices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `AppCompatActivity` extended `Activity` because, when you set up the `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar` with `setSupportActionBar(Toolbar)` you get the ability to reference it through `Context.getSupportActionBar()` from nearly anywhere in your code i.e `Fragment`. But, if you don't extend `AppCompatActivity` you can't easily get a reference to the `Toolbar` from anywhere else other than the `Activity` in which it was defined.