# How to add app bar in YouTube player activity?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

How to add action bar in YouTube player?

I'm trying to add action bar in this activity, but because it's not extended to `AppCompatActivity` that's why I'm getting an error in `getSupportActionBar();`. I'm also getting error if I replace the `YouTubeBaseActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public class ActivityPlayer extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public String DEVELOPER_KEY = "key";
    public String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = "5z-Roo_NpI4";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(youTubeView, "There was an error initializing the video player.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setDuration(5000).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.loadVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);
            player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? can you add it to your question?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 The error i'm getting in `getSupportActionBar();` if I extend the activity to `YouTubeBaseActivity`. Means `public class Player extends YouTubeBaseActivity` can't resolve symbol `getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: And also if I do extend the activity to `AppCompatActivity` the app crashes and says that YouTubePlayer should be extended to `YouTubeBaseActivity`. That's all of my errors!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem with you, I'm posting an answer in case you or others still need a work around. Forget about `YoutubeBaseActivity` and focus on `YoutubePlayerSupportFragment` because Fragment let you setup your Activity as you wish. There is `YoutubePlayerFragment` also but the Support version of it work better with android support libraries.

Here's is the Steps I used :

1. Make your activity Extends AppCompatActivity

   ```
   public class ActivityPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {
   ```
2. Add a FrameLayout in xml layout of the Current Activity that extends AppCompatActivity (activity_main.xml)

   ```
    <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/flYoutube"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:visibility="visible" />
   ```
3. Create a YoutubeFragment extends Fragment, with fragment_youtube.xml layout and a FrameLayout inside of it. And in onCreateView, create a YoutubePlayerSupportFragment instance and replace the FrameLayout within the fragment_youtube.xml with that instance of YoutubePlayerSupportFragment.

   ```
   public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {
       private static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "8S7K4hEVhgOQ87501j-FAKE-KEY";

       // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
       private static final String VIDEO_ID = "VIDEO_ID";

       // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
       private String videoId;

       public YoutubeFragment() {
           // Required empty public constructor
       }


       public static YoutubeFragment newInstance(String videoId) {
           YoutubeFragment fragment = new YoutubeFragment();
           Bundle args = new Bundle();
           args.putString(VIDEO_ID, videoId);
           fragment.setArguments(args);
           return fragment;
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           if (getArguments() != null) {
               videoId = getArguments().getString(VIDEO_ID);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // Inflate the layout for this fragment
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube, container, false);

           YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
           FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           transaction.replace(R.id.flYoutubePlayer, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

           youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

               @Override
               public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                   if (!b) {
                       //youTubePlayer.setFullscreen(true);
                       youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
                       //yoTubePlayer.play();
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               }
           });

           return rootView;
       }

   }
   ```
4. Create a 2nd FrameLayout in fragment_youtube.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context="jfsl.ayibopost.fragments.YoutubeFragment">

       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/flYoutubePlayer"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp"></FrameLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
5. Last thing to do in PlayerActivity onCreate(), is to create an instance of your own created YoutubeFragment and replace the Frame Layouts within the activity_main.xml with that YoutubeFragment instance via Fragment Transaction:

   ```
   // Create Youtube Fragment instance by passing a Youtube Video ID
   YoutubeFragment youtubeFragment = YoutubeFragment.newInstance("2zNSgSzhBfM");
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.flYoutube, youtubeFragment).commit();
   ```

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement an `AppCompatCallback` interface.

Please, see my [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358046/how-can-an-activity-use-a-toolbar-without-extending-appcompatactivity/58825227#58825227)